# Iterating through a list of lists and comparing current and last elements

Tags: python, list, compare

Apologies if this is already covered in another thread.  I'm a bit new with Python (3, specifically), so perhaps the answer was given to a conceptually similar question and I missed the relevance.

I am looping through a list of lists, similar to the following:

```
biglist = [[a, b, x, d], [a, b, x, d], [a, b, y, d], [a, b, y, d], [a, b, z, d], [a, b, x, d]]
```

I would like to conditionally perform certain actions whenever the third element in a given sublist is different than the third element in the previous sublist.  In the above example, this would happen for the third sublist (y != x), the fifth sublist (z != y) and the sixth sublist (x != z).

Whenever such non-matches occur, I would like to modify the corresponding first element in the current sublist. (Note - I know not to generally change a list while iterating through it, but I believe it is ok to modify other elements of a list of a list [as opposed to adding or removing entries]. For instance, in the above situation, I would like the loop to produce the following altered big list:

```
biglist = [[a, b, x, d], [a, b, x, d], [new_a, b, y, d], [a, b, y, d], [new_a, b, z, d], [new_a, b, x, d]]
```

After spending a few hours playing with an index and reading through other threads, I'm still stuck.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Iterate over the outer list in pairs of inner lists, then `if second[2] != first[2]: second[0] = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code achieves the outcome you desire:

```
biglist = [['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'],
           ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'],
           ['a', 'b', 'y', 'd'],
           ['a', 'b', 'y', 'd'],
           ['a', 'b', 'z', 'd'],
           ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd']]

for i in range(len(biglist)):
    if i > 0:
        if biglist[i][2] != biglist[i-1][2]:
            biglist[i][0] = 'new_' + biglist[i][0]

print(biglist)
```

Using python 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over pairs of elements I typically do this:

```
for x,y in zip(biglist, itertools.islice(biglist, 1, None)):
    print(x, y)
```

From there, you compare the third elements of the two lists and update the second list's first element if they don't match:

```
import itertools

biglist = [['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'y', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'y', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'z', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd']]

for x,y in zip(biglist, itertools.islice(biglist, 1, None)):
    if x[2] != y[2]:
        y[0] = 'new' + y[0]

import pprint
pprint.pprint(biglist)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'x', 'd'],
 ['newa', 'b', 'y', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'y', 'd'],
 ['newa', 'b', 'z', 'd'],
 ['newa', 'b', 'x', 'd']]
```

Comment: This makes a (near) copy of `biglist`, which might be expensive.

Comment: To avoid making a copy, use *itertools.izip()* and *itertools.islice()*.

Comment: Good idea. I've updated the code to use islice. OP mentioned python 3, so I kept zip (instead of izip).

Comment: This is great; thanks. Need to familiarize myself with the itertools functionality, but this looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate iterators. It's not often you create an iterator on a list explicitly, as opposed to letting a `for` loop create it implicitly, but here is a case where it is useful.

```
iter1 = iter(biglist)
iter2 = iter(biglist)
next(iter2)   # advance the second iterator

for prev, curr in itertools.izip(iter1, iter2):
    if prev[2] != curr[2]:
        curr[0] = 'new_' + curr[0]
```

You are correct that it is safe to modify a sublist while iterating over the outer list, because the outer list itself is not changed.

You can also use `itertools.islice` (as suggested by Raymond Hettinger) instead of manually consuming the first element of the second iterator.

```
from itertools import izip, islice
for prev, curr in izip(biglist, islice(biglist, 1, None)):
```